# Change HTML textarea with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, button, textarea

I have the following code in the HTML:

```
<button onclick="showDescription();">Find book</button>
```

While in the JavaScript file attached:

```
function showDescription(){
    document.getElementById("description").value="book";
}
```

However, whenever I click the button, it only shows the string "book" for 1 second, and disappears. Any idea what went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your button is (presumably) inside a `<form>`.

The default type for a button is `submit`.

1. The JavaScript runs
2. The value is updated
3. The form is submitted
4. The page is reloaded
5. The initial value is displayed again

Don't use a submit button:

```
<button type="button" onclick="showDescription();">Find book</button>
```

Alternatively, return false from your event handler:

```
onclick="showDescription(); return false;"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that button is inside a form, change it from :

```
<button onclick="showDescription();">Find book</button>
```

to:

```
<input type="button" onclick="showDescription();" value="Find book" />
```

A button has a default type of submit, so it will submit the form and reload the page if it's inside a form element.

Comment: That won't work. The event handler still isn't returning false.

Comment: Yeah, you're right! Once I move the button out of the form, it works. Regarding the showDescription function, why shall we return false?

Comment: My bad, you have to return false in the event handler or change the elements type or just change to an input.

Comment: Wait, but why should we return false here?

Comment: You return false to prevent the default action of the button, which is to submit the form, which will reload the page, like a form submit always does.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function showDescription()
            {
                document.getElementById("description").innerHTML="book";
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <button onclick="showDescription();">Find book</button>

        <textarea id="description" rows="4" cols="50">
        </textarea>

    </body>
```